# How were ancient books divided?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-request, book

Nowadays, books are divided into chapters, chapters into sections, sections into subsections, and so on.

Is there an equivalent hierarchy in Latin (I'm mainly asking about classical Latin, but maybe later Latin too)?
E.g. liber/capitulum/etc.

Answer (score 4):

Greek and Roman works were generally divided into “books” (libri), each book filling one roll of papyrus. So if a work consists of five books, the whole work would be contained on five rolls. Each book can be subdivided into “headings” (singular caput), but this is not so common in the classical period.

Comment: Thanks, is there a difference between caput and capitulum?

Comment: Capitulum is a diminutive of caput.